# Selenium links request

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to download python.exe from the site using selenium. So I'm using that code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.python.org/downloads/")
    try:
        c = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT,"Download 
    Python 3.8.2"))
        c.click()
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

But the shell always say:

```
   TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is the issue? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `()`:

```
presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Download Python 3.8.2")))
```